# MS Graph Api: cannot retrieve a specific user's calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have an asp.net core app that authenticates users from my company's Office 365 AAD.

I have requested this delegated permissions: User.Read.All, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared

I authenticate on the graph api with on behalf workflow.

In my outlook web interface I can see my calendar, S calendar and E calendar
[image]

If I run this graph query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
```

I have my three users, evrything is ok!

Now for each users if I run this query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
```

This works fine for all three users

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendars
```

Running this query works only for me, for the two other  users, using the default office 365 configuration, it returns 404 - Not Found with the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "date": "2020-03-12T17:46:58"
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I ask one of my users to give me full access to his calendar this query works.

So, my question is why I can see all three calendars in outlook web interface and why I can't see it with the graph api?

Comment: Hey,
I think there's an issue with your requested scopes there. 

As far as i remember the "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared" gives you access to all calendars the CURRENT user owns or has access to. Thats why it works when one of your users shares the calendar. 

If you want to access all user's calendars you have to use the service/demon flow and scopes and this also requires admin permission when consenting.

Comment: What I really want is to see the calendars I have in outlook webapp in my application. Using the service/demon flow gives me full access to calendar and I don't want that.

Comment: Well the scope should give you access to all of them yea. Are you sure its all user calendars and not like public folder ones?